# Повтор предлогов

Tags: стилистика

Часто в текстах сталкиваюсь с такой ситуацией, когда встречается вынужденный повтор предлогов, употребляемых в разном значении. Вот, как раз в предыдущем вопросе как раз встретился такой случай: "в письме в газету". Допустимо ли это такое в литературном тексте или лучше этого избегать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Принципиального запрета нет. А куда деваться, если это надо по смыслу фразы?
Но если можно безболезненно заменить, то лучше это сделать, потому что часто возникают сложности восприятия, причем именно в письменном тексте.